# Use input boxes for HH:MM, instead of using a slider in jQuery Datepicker (with Timepicker)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I've been using the jQuery UI Datepicker with the Timepicker addon ([this is the one I'm talking about](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples)). But instead of using a slider to pick my time (HH:MM), I was wondering if there is a way I can replace the slider with two input fields (one each for HH, MM).

I looked around and there ARE other datepickers with this functionality, but I'm looking more for an extension to the original Datepicker UI (basically because I love the look and feel of this little widget).

**EDIT**

I went through the documentation again (I actually had to read it line by line this time) and found that you can indeed customize the way your datatimepicker shows the HH:MM. There is a section just before the 'Alternate Fields' that explains how to do it - [Timepicker addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#alt_examples).

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: read the docs..can change control to `<select>`